# How use function downloadFile

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have used Drive's [PHP download api](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads), but when I call it, it doesn't do anything: `$httpRequest=downloadFile($service, $file);` - the downloadUrl is not empty.

```
function downloadFile($service, $file) {
  $downloadUrl = $file->getDownloadUrl();
  if ($downloadUrl) {
    $request = new Google_HttpRequest($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
    $httpRequest = Google_Client::$io->authenticatedRequest($request);
    if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
      return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
    } else {
      // An error occurred.
      return null;
    }
  } else {
    // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
    return null;
  }
}
```

How do I correctly download a file from Google Drive?

Comment: on another page I found this code: 

    $requestedFile = json_decode(downloadFile($service, $file));
    print_r($requestedFile);

but does not work.

Comment: "Does not work" is not an error message or useful fault report. Have you debugged this? What is your HTTP response code? Does function execute the inner or outer `else`, and if so, which one?

Comment: This code gave no error messages. It just did nothing.

Comment: Debug then please - as it stands, that's what someone here would have to do in order to see what is going on. Of course, only you can do that at present! I did ask some other questions above - please answer them.

Comment: Could you tell what the function returned? IS it null?